# How to sum values for the empty cells in a column, considering the first non-empty value on the left

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this in a Google Sheets spreadsheet

| ItemID | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | ... |
| Item2 | 14 |  |  |  |  |
| Item3 | 9 | 8 |  | 8 | ... |
| Item4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |  | ... |
| Item5 |  |  | 10 | 10 | ... |
| Item6 |  |  | 17 | 17 | ... |

This is a pivot table, that automatically adds a new column whenever new data comes.

Based on that, I am trying to get a Deleted statistics, like this:

| Value | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 37 | 22 | 43 | 45 | ... |
| Deleted | 0 | 14 | 22 | 19 |  |

Basically, the value for Deleted on each date would be the sum of the first non-empty value on the left for each empty value on that specific date. For instance, in Date4, Item2 and Item4 are empty, so I need to sum 14 and 5.
How can I write the Deleted value as a formula, without creating a new column? Is it possible?

I found a way to retrieve the value on the left based on a range, using an adapted version of the function proposed in https://support.google.com/docs/thread/187187800/how-to-find-last-not-empty-cell-in-a-row?hl=en, but I do not know how to use that on a conditional sum to achieve what i need.

Answer (score 2):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(range_,B:E, bycol(sequence(1,columns(range_)),lambda(Σ,let(x,choosecols(range_,Σ),vstack(sum(x),
     if(Σ=1,0,sum(iferror(byrow(filter(choosecols(range_,sequence(Σ-1)),x=""),lambda(Λ,choosecols(torow(Λ,1),-1)))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I had to read and try it out several times to understand and adapt to the real case I am dealing with, but it worked! Tks! If I may ask one more thing, to make it even more robust: when I have more columns added to the dataset (more Dates), I have to edit the range_ expression. Is that a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Can you explain with an example on what you meant by dynamic?!

Comment: For instance, if I add a new column Date5 to the original table, I would need to change formula to `=let(range_,B:F,...`, so I process the new column. It would be nice to have range `B:F` defined dinamically, considering the existence of a new date column. It might check the last non empty column in line 1, for instance, to delimit range.

Comment: Use: `=choosecols(indirect("Sheet1!B1:"&rows(Sheet1!A:A)),sequence(index(match(,0/(Sheet1!B1:1<>"")))))` (assuming the tab name as **Sheet1** here)